# How django gets values of serializer fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I can't figure out how and where Django gets the value of the field which value is another serializer.  I need to get a place where something like `FirstSerializer(data)` happens for the following example:

```
class FirstSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...

class SecondSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    first = FirstSerializer()
    ...

class ThirdSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    second = SecondSerializer()
    ...

class TripleView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ThirdSerializer
    ...
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe it is because of the relationship. In your `SecondSerializer` the `first` variable has a relationship with the model in `FirstSerializer`

Comment: @DiegoMagalhães Yes, and I want to find the place where ```FirstSerialzier(data)``` is assigned to the ```first```

Comment: You needs to dig down the library code base to understand this. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py